# Swift: Best way to add one single image to all cells in a UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a large image for the background of table cells (to support all devices and orientations). Since I want to save memory I thought it would be a good idea to make an UIImage with the correct dimensions in the ViewDidLoad:

```
let bgImage = UIImage(named: "cellBG_001.png")
var bgView = UIImageView()
bgView = UIImageView(image: bgImage!)
bgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
```

and then re-use this for every cell. Then I learned that a view can only have one parent view and ended with the same code, but in the **cellForRowAtIndexPath**-method. Now I feel bad about that ; ) is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just create one `UIImage` object and then assign it to all `UIImageView`s in your cells. Also since `UITableView` is reusing cells you shouldn't have problems with performance if you are dequeueing cells.

Comment: Thanks! So a resizing before shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: You don't need to resize images when you are using `UIImageView`. Apple has implemented this well, and all you need to worry about is `imageView.contentMode` to display it the way you like.